# Which fonts are safe for use on the web today?

Tags: font

The fonts that were allowed for use on the web are limited. But over the last few years, the fonts that could be safely used on a web page for styling elements have increased. In this day, which fonts can be used safely?

Comment: This would probably be better asked on [Graphic Design SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This isn't really suitable for this site, answers would just consist of a whole list of examples with no correct answer. As per the [FAQ] *"We prefer questions that elicit definitive answers or solutions rather than prolonged discussions. Remember, this a Q&A site, not a discussion board."* If you can reword it so that it's a specific question then we can re-open this question for you.

Comment: There's no longer such thing as "web safe" fonts. Though there are some fonts that Chrome on Windows doesn't render very well...

Answer (score 5):

With `@font-face` avaliable for you to embed fonts, the choices of avaliable fonts in ALL modern browsers are essentially unlimited.

Here's a list of browsers that support `@font-face`:

- Google Chrome: version 4.249.4+
- Mozilla Firefox: version: 3.5+
- Apple Safari: version 3.1+
- Opera: version 10.5+
- Microsoft Internet Explorer: version 6+

I personally use [Google Webfont](http://www.google.com/webfonts/) for most of my new projects if I require a different font. The fonts are served over Google's CDN and contain the right headers and etags to prevent redownloads.

This is a good guide on [how to make your own webfonts](http://boldperspective.com/2011/how-to-use-css-font-face/) (from existing fonts).

As a backup, ensure that you have defined a font family incase the browser does not support `@font-face`:

```
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; //The default sans serif font will be used if PT Sans is not avaliable.
```